# radial-gradient causing errant requests to server

Tags: css, browser

We're seeing a lot of errant requests to our nginx server of the form:

```
2013/12/03 14:59:45 [error] 17414#0: *22246042 open()
"/srv/example/current/public/assets/texture.png), radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner, "
failed (2: No such file or directory),
client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: www.example.com, 
request: "GET /assets/texture.png),%20radial-gradient(ellipse%20farthest-corner,%20 HTTP/1.1",
host: "www.example.com",
referrer: "https://www.example.com/"
```

It seems as though someone's browser is interpreting our radial-gradient CSS as part of the asset URL.  The relevant CSS rule:

```
.example {
  background-color: #3e7213;
  /* FF 3.6+ */
  background-image: url(/assets/texture.png), -moz-radial-gradient(center center, ellipse farthest-corner, #65981e, #184d08);
  /* IE10 */
  background-image: url(/assets/texture.png), -ms-radial-gradient(center center, ellipse farthest-corner, #65981e, #184d08);
  /* Safari 4+, Chrome 2+ */
  background-image: url(/assets/texture.png), -webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 50%, 0, 50% 50%, 560, from(#65981e), to(#184d08));
  /* Safari 5.1+, Chrome 10+ */
  background-image: url(/assets/texture.png), -webkit-radial-gradient(center center, ellipse farthest-corner, #65981e, #184d08);
  /* Opera 11.10 */
  background-image: url(/assets/texture.png), -o-radial-gradient(center center, ellipse farthest-corner, #65981e, #184d08);
  /* CSS3 standard */
  background-image: url(/assets/texture.png), radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner, #65981e, #184d08);
}
```

Is it an old browser mis-parsing the rule?

Comment: Could it be that you're using commas to separate the css selector properties instead of semi-colons?

Comment: You might try putting the actual url in quotes, `url('/assets/texture.png')`. I really don't know if that will solve the issue or not, but it almost seems like the final parenthesis is getting ignored for the url, and prehaps the quotes will "help" that browser.